# How to cite authors from any country correctly?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

It has always seemed to me that the Mathematical Community gives a high importance to the act of properly citing an author (Do not write Erdos! It's Erdős. Cauchy must be read as in French, not as in English...).

Hence, I thought that it might be useful to ask your opinion about how to cite correctly a foreign and/or complicated author name in the references.
It seems that Bibtex handles only standard English style names well, and requires many workarounds for foreign names (see [here](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-23.html)). So it is better not to count on it too much.

Feel free to point out any suggestion, or even the problems you have come across when citing authors.

I'll start a list:

- ✔ **First, Middle, Last - Names.** 
  OK, I think there are no doubts, "John Horton Conway" should be cited as "J. H. Conway". Note the whitespaces after each period.
- ✔ **Spanish names:** See the very good answer of Leo Alonso.
- ✔ **"Nobiliary" names (von, van der, etc.):** See the answer of 
  R. van Dobben de Bruyn.
- **Chinese names:** Here I am often in trouble. I read that Chinese write their surname first and then their given name, but I think that in papers they are usually swapped. Also I heard that many Chinese have the same surname.

**THE FREE LOOKUP ANSWERS**

- The user zeno pointed out that the tool MRLookUp http://www.ams.org/mrlookup is free an can be used to get the bibtex of any article tracked by the AMS.
- Federico Poloni also suggested MRef http://www.ams.org/mref.

**THE "LET'S JUST CLOSE" ANSWERS**

Some users voted to close this question for different reasons. I answered this question thinking that how to cite an author correctly is often a problem for mathematicians, so address it on MO could have been useful for many users. I can agreed to close this question, probably choosing zeno answer as the best, BUT before I would like to see more comments and opinions, especially about Asian names.

**NOTES:**

1) Many answered: "just look on MathSciNet". Unfortunately, MathSciNet is not free for everyone, so I think this is a quite unsatisfactory method.

2) The question is not about the transliteration of names, you can assume that the author already have a name written in a reasonable set of characters extending the Latin. The question is about the abbreviation of names in references.

Comment: I just download the bibtex from mathscinet. Job done. If you don't have access to mathscinet then probably the most sensible thing is to find not the article you're citing but a published paper which references the article you're citing, and copy that. This isn't a maths question -- it should be on academia.stackexchange .

Comment: Your remark about Chinese names is correct, and it is unfortunate. The names 'Wang', 'Chen', 'Zhang', 'Li' are the most common. Moreover, many people in China have a single syllable given name. What's even more vexing is that many distinct names in Chinese turn into the same name in English. For instance ‘汪维’ and ‘王伟’ are completely distinct, and no Chinese person will confuse the two... but both of them turn into 'Wang Wei' in pinyin (which is also how it's spelt in English)

Comment: @eric: This is how errors in bibliographies propagate (and there are plenty). See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1659886/ .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to academia.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Relevant thread: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/should-i-cite-author-names-as-they-appear-in-the-journal-or-as-i-know-them-to-be

Comment: @Dirk I do not think my question belongs to Academia.SE because I am sure that in different fields of Science there are different standards and traditions in how an author name in cited. My question ask how to cite properly in math articles.

Comment: As a frequent user of academia.sx I am not aware of different cultures regarding names in different fields of science (as long as the order in not concerned!), hence my vote to migrate.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't agree with your remark. Mathscinet has a much lower error rate than the average mathematician who doesn't spend hours doing bibliography searches. Also, this is how errors in bibilographies gets fixed: someone submits a correction to Mathscinet, once, and then it's there for everyone. :)

Comment: @Dirk Really? I admit I have no evidence that goes against your claim, but it does surprise me slightly

Comment: @yemonchoi May mathematicians are sometimes not that different...

Comment: I vote to close as "primarily opinion-based", as the existing answers show...

Comment: Names are also written surname-first in Hungarian. Therefore, Erdős is a great example. In Hungary, the proper way to write Erdős` name would be _Erdős Pál_. However, in scientific papers, his name is written Paul Erdős. I am not sure why only the last name is written true to his origin, or if it is only his preference.

Comment: In favor of not migrating: the *question* has nothing specific to mathematics, but the *answers* definitely do. Most other academic fields do not have the fortune of having a great literature database which produces (generally) high-quality bibtex files.

Comment: Am I alone in wishing that names appeared also in their original languages, at least in full citations? Thus, we would have Wang, W. (王伟). And I might be Moskovich, D. (מוסקוביץ, ד.)
This is wishful thinking/ dreaming, I know...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's well said. In view of the answers and the comments a migration, this thread would probably appear a bit odd at academia.sx. I retracted my close vote…

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Now the most common Chinese surname would be 赵.

Comment: @DanielMoskovich You are not alone, but in fact in good company. Don Knuth is meticulous about writing the names in the original script, so at least in the index of his books the names are in the original as well as transliterated script (not so for citations though)...

Comment: @Suvrit, does he alphabetise by transliteration?  If not, then how *does* he alphabetise?  (I was told once, though probably it's not true, that Chinese doesn't even *have* a natural total order.)

Comment: Portugese, anyone?

Comment: I think the situation with non-Latin names brings up an interesting question about Western names: Latin alphabets vary among Western countries. Should we simplify all of them into the 26 characters of English, or should we maintain characters like é (like in Czech), å (Scandinavian), ø (e.g. Danish, Norwegian), ł (e.g. Polish), etc? If Chinese, Russian, Arabic, etc names are not spelled in their original alphabet, where do we draw the line? (All examples I gave are considered separate characters in their respective alphabets. In French, é is not considered a separate letter in the alphabet.)

Comment: (To answer my own question: I think that trying to maintain as much of the original language as possible is desirable. That said, I don't think we will get to a point soon where we want to have *only* the Chinese spelling, without a Western interpretation to accompany it...)

Answer (score 40):

MathSciNet is not free, but MRLookUp 
http://www.ams.org/mrlookup
is free. So just look it up there and copy the bibtex.

Comment: This is the best answer. If MathSciNet's database contains a citation that an author does not like (e.g. because of an issue with names) then this issue will be reported and fixed. Good on the AMS for making this resource free.

Comment: I use MathSciNet too, but occasionally (quite rarely) there are mistakes in the MathSciNet bibtex code.

Comment: So email the AMS and tell them about them. I'm sure they'll be grateful! I once emailed them because I caught a duplicate in MathSciNet and they seemed very pleased to be able to fix it.

Comment: @eric I do let them know of some mistakes, I'm just pointing out it's not 100% accurate.

Comment: There is also Zentralblatt https://zbmath.org/ which is more generous with their data towards non-subscribers than MathSciNet.

Comment: Example: [Johann Melchior Ernst Karl Gerlach Stückelberg von Breidenbach zu Breidenstein und Melsbach](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Stueckelberg.html) $\to$ [Stueckelberg, Ernest-C.-G.](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/MRAuthorID/546360) Done!

Answer (score 22):

**For spaniards names.**

A spaniard has a given name that sometimes is two (even more) like *Pedro*, *Pablo*, *Juan Luis*, *María Eugenia*, etc. The second given name is recognized because it is usually different from the usual family names. It is possible to have a family names like *Carlos*, but it is not quite frequent.

Additionally all the people has two family names, the first comes from the father's family and the second from mother's the family. Roughly this second family name works as the "middle initial" in some English speaking countries.

So, a mathematician named José Luis García Pérez should be cited like

```
García Pérez, José L.
```

In real life you might call him José, José Luis, or perhaps Pepe.

A really brief way and of course correct of referring to him is

```
García, J. L.
```

He might be tired of explaining this subtleties to editors and authors and write his name as José Luis García-Pérez, avoiding references to him as prof. Pérez instead of the correct prof. García. But this solution is not really compatible with the legal use stablished in Spain.

It happens that some people have complicated family names like Francisco Javier de la Vega Martínez, then the citation should be

```
Vega Martínez, Francisco J. de la
```

and the short version

```
Vega, F. de la
```

Another source of possible confusion is people with composite last names like, say Pedro Antonio García-Valcárcel Rodríguez. Then the composite works a single last name and most of the time its is not abbreviated. Perhaps in a desperate situation one might out an abbreviation for the first of the two because it is usually the more common. A citation should read

```
García-Valcárcel Rodríguez, Pedro A.
```

and the (extra) short version

```
G.-Valcárcel, P.
```

I think I am covering the several cases. Now for the extremely complicated example in the question: Juan Pablo Fernández de Calderón García-Iglesias. The name "Juan" is the first given name, thus the main one, "Pablo" is the second given name, "Fernández de Calderón" is the first last name, so the main one and "García-Iglesias" is a composite second last name. The right way of citation:

```
Fernández de Calderón García-Iglesias, Juan P.
```

a short version

```
Fernández de Calderón, J.
```

And if you are really out of space the following

```
Fdez. de Calderón, J.
```

would be possible. There are other variants but I think I've covered the key points.

Comment: Thank you a lot Leo Alonso, I edited my question as the case of Spanish names has been answered by you.

Comment: My pleasure. I have had a lot of problems when some people cites my papers, and send them to wikipedia's page Spanish naming conventions. Now I have an alternate source.

Answer (score 19):

One thing that some people don't know is that in some languages, nobiliary particles¹ are neither capitalised (unless they appear at the beginning of the name; i.e. when initials are omitted)² nor alphabetised. In Dutch, for example, *van*, *de*, *van der*, etc are ignored for alphabetisation purposes. In Flemish names, however, the particles are usually both alphabetised and capitalised.

**Example.** (Dutch) *B. L. van der Waerden* should be under W, not V. Another format³ would be *Waerden, B. L. van der*.

**Example.** (German) *C. L. F. von Lindemann* should be under L, not V.

**Example.** (French) *P. de Fermat* should be under F, not D.

**Example.** (Flemish) *M. Van den Bergh* is under V! Note also the capitalisation of *Van*, but not *den*. This is presumably because the V occurs at the beginning of the name.

However, it seems that sometimes theorems named after people with such names may or may not (presumably depending on the country) drop the particle altogether: e.g. *Fermat's little theorem*, *Lindemann–Weierstraß theorem*. In (modern) Dutch, you would never do this; e.g. *De Bruijn–Erdős theorem* (note that *De* is capitalised, since the initials are omitted).

**Remark.** I find it entertaining to see that some authors are aware of these rules and others aren't (or does it depend on their BibTeX setup?). Next time you try to find a name of this form in the references, take a look at how the author alphabetised it.

**Conclusion.** Every country has different conventions, and it's very confusing. However, the strategy of following what the author uses herself is a safe one.

---

¹Their name is somewhat misleading: they do not always indicate nobility (e.g. in the Netherlands they don't).

²I believe that in German, the particle is omitted altogether if the surname is not preceded by the initials.

³This is the Dutch format. I don't know the conventions of other countries.

Comment: Note that in German only common particles are ignored. In a German library you will find tom Dieck under t, and von zur Gathen under z .

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to add your answer in the list.

Answer (score 12):

EDIT. As Dirk pointed, when you cite a paper (written in Latin font) you always
write the author's name exactly as it is written in the paper.

When you cite a paper which is written in some other alphabet,
the following are two reasonable approaches to this that I know: 1. To follow Mathscinet.
2. If an author ever wrote a paper using Latin font, write his name as he did himself.

Of course these approaches give the same result in most cases, but the second is especially important when you cite old authors who are not in Mathscinet,
for example, Chebyshev. (There was a nice joke in one combinatorics book: Problem. How many ways are there to spell Tschebyschev in English?).

It happens that the same author (or the translator) wrote his name with different spellings in different papers in English. In this case, when you cite his paper, just follow the spelling in the paper that you cite.

EDIT. Here is a little example which shows how good the Mathscinet author database is. American mathematician D. F. Shea once published a paper in a Ukrainian journal, in Russian, and this paper was later translated to English. The translator of the paper transliterated his name from Russian as "Shia". Nevertheless Mathscinet determined his identity correctly.

EDIT2. There is a remarkable book on the subject of Chebysheff's names (first and last), and many other related important subjects:

The Thread: A Mathematical Yarn Paperback 
by Philip J. Davis , 1989.

Strongly recommended.
However, the author is not a native Russian speaker, so he does not discuss such advanced topics as the one in @Fedor Petrov comment.

Comment: I think only the last sentence gives the correct approach (unless you are D. Knuth).

Comment: About approach 1: unfortunately, Mathscinet is not free, I'm going to add a remark to my question. About approach 2: Usually when an author write a paper he write his complete name under the title, not an abbreviation of it, so I do not understand how this could be helpful. Probably I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Dirk: you are right of course. And this does not contradict 1,2, because Mathscinet also uses this rule. The main question is what to do when the cited paper is not written in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @Fry: Mathscinet is not free. Neither most journals are. 2. I did not understand this remark of yours. But I think author's name in the reference list should match the one on his paper, abbreviated or not.

Comment: @Fry Mathscinet is not free, but [mref](http://www.ams.org/mref) is, and has the same results with a slightly more inconvenient search interface.

Comment: It is not well-known but Zentralblatt is partially free. I mean you can use it free with reduced features. If yu are smart, you can extract really a lot from it with these reduced features.

Comment: Cheney, W. and Kincaid, D. R. Numerical Mathematics and Computing, 3rd ed. Brooks/Cole, 1994, Ex. 14, p. 16, suggests $40$ possibilities for Чебышёв but excludes many, including those which have the final vowel phonetically as *o* rather than *e* (it rhymes with the Soviet leaders *Gorbachev/ov* and *Khrushchev/ov*)

Comment: The joke I've heard is that Chebyshev's Inequality states that no two mathematicians will spell his name the same way.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: you will be probably surprised to learn that even among the Russian speakers there is no agreement how to spell his name in Russian and even how to pronounce it. (Russian pronounciation somewhat changed since then).

Comment: @Dirk Trivia: journal websites (and the bibtex they produce) mis-spell your name [even if you're the world-famous D. Knuth](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088508817636). The PDF has the correct spelling, though.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Wow, this is great! I emailed TandfF about this and let's see if they are as dedicated as MathSciNet…

Comment: As suspected: ResearchGate and Google Scholar also have the wrong name while MathSciNet has this correct…

Comment: Mathscinet authors database is very good: it is amazing how well they are able to identify various spellings of foreign authors.Unlike other databases, this one is made by people, not by computers.

Comment: In Russian he is spelled Чебышев (not Чебышёв) and pronounced as Чебышёв (not Чебышев). Simple as that.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: Very nice observation. Letter \"e was introduced after Chebyshev's birth. And it is still ignored in many Russian texts. I added a remark to my answer addressing your comment.

Comment: Letter ё was introduced about 30 years before his birth, but much after his family got a surname. This is why he insisted on writing Чебышев: this is a sign that his family is old.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: As I remember, this letter was introduced by Karamzin, but do not know in what year. Anyway, it seems evident that it was accepted very slowly, and still is not fully accepted:-)

Comment: Concerning Chebyshev, see http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/math696/spelling-lesson.html.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko it's absurd to write "Cheby**ch**eff"

Comment: The set of possible writings of Чебышев/Чебышёв in English is contained in the set Cheb$\{$i,y$\}$sh$\{$e,ë,o,yo$\}\{$v,f,ff$\}$. The combination Tsch-sch is German transliteration.

Answer (score 8):

Two somewhat similar points:

1)  When it comes to choosing a correct spelling, I disagree with Alexandre Eremenko that one should follow the spelling in the cited paper.  I think one should always use the spelling under which the person is best known.

Let's say you are citing several papers by Erdős, some with a non-standard spelling (MathSciNet also lists Erdös, Erdós, Erdőš, etc.)  Are you going to have several different spelling of the same author?  Only in the references or in the main body of the paper as well?  This only creates a confusion and serves no clear purpose (MSN merges all spellings anyway).

Some Russian names gives more unfortunate examples. Are you going to cite Oleinik or Oleĭnik?  Gelfand or Gel'fand?  The latter spelling is standard in both cases, but few non-Russian speakers would know how to pronounce the names in that case - these extra symbols again create an unnecessary confusion.

2)  For Chinese and other foreign names - again, the golden rule is to use the name they are best known.  I recommend reading this [Wikipedia guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(people)) which I found to be well thought out and quite helpful.

Comment: Thing is that "best known" is subjective… Or do you mean "best known to yourself"? An example from outside academia: Is is [T.C. Boyle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._C._Boyle), [T. Coraghessan Boyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._Coraghessan_Boyle) or Tom Coraghessan Boyle?

Comment: Not really.  I recommend google test.  Alternatively, MathSciNet has a preferred spelling, listing all other spellings in the author profile under "Published as"

Comment: For Stanley J. Osher your MathSciNet and Google do not agree for me (let alone that googling is itself subjective): MathSciNet suggests "Stanley J. Osher" while "S. Osher" produces most Google hits for me ("Stanley Osher" is second place and "S. J. Osher" is third place). Another nice try is "Jeffrey C. Lagarias"…

Comment: I remember an epic thread in Russian blogs on how to call Shiing-Shen Chern ("American" Черн, most common, or "Chinese" Чжень, used in old Russian texts, before he came to U.S.) There were hundreds of comments, but no agreement.

Comment: I strongly object. After all what is the purpose of the reference list? Is not that for the reader to find the cited paper? You will facilitate the task by writing the author's name EXACTLY as written in the paper. And YES, sometimes one has to cite the same author with different spellings. This is actually very common with names written in Cyrilic.

Comment: The "best known" rule does not seem to work well with people who have changed their name (e.g., women who changed their name upon marriage and published under both names) or who have used a pseudonym.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko -- this is *my* point, actually.  How is the person supposed to search for "Oleĭnik" in the MathSciNet if one cannot type it?  You search for "Oleinik" and find the right paper.

Comment: @Tim Chow -- good point.  I guess I would use the original name X in the citation and in the body of the paper use "as proved by Y (nee X) in [X], we have.."

Comment: @Igor Pak: Just try with Mathscinet the experiment you propose.

Comment: @TimothyChow -- I guess the same goes for men :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is also the singular case of [Yahya ould Hamidoune, *the* Mauritanian mathematician](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8357133). In fact, *ould* is not a name: it just means 'the son of'. It is used in the same spirit of the Italian patronyms *de* or *de'* (as in [Bruno de Finetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_de_Finetti) or [Lorenzo de' Medici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenzo_de'_Medici)), so it should be treated in the very same way. However, most of Hamidoune's papers are cited (or even signed by Hamidoune himself!) as if 'Yahya' and 'ould' were two first names, which is why you will typically read 'H. O. Hamidoune' or 'Hamidoune, H. O.' in bibliographies. (In still other cases, matters are just cut short by dropping the 'ould'.)

In an ideal world, I think the mistake (if you also take it as such) should be definitely fixed: Hamidoune's papers would be indexed as 'H. ould Hamidoune' or 'ould Hamidoune, H.' (depending on the journal style), and ordered by making reference only to 'Hamidoune' (if they have to be ordered alphabetically). But I'm urged to be realistic: this won't happen for many reasons.

Comment: The *Fi* of *Fibonacci* is also a particle meaning *son of*, but citing him as Leonardo Bonacci would be to value pedantry over effective communication.